# How to use Turnbull's nonparametric estimator for interval-censored data in R

Tags: r, estimation, survival

I am doing Survival Analysis with interval-censored data and I want to apply Turnbull's nonparametric estimator to the analysis of the covariates (suggested by Turnbull (1976)).

I want to know if there anyone knows any statistical package in R wich produces the survival curve estimate based on Turnbull´s algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the Non-Parametric Maximum Likelihood Estimator (NPMLE) (what Turnbull 1976's algorithm computes), you could use the `interval` package.

I believe the default uses the standard EM algorithm as presented by Turnbull...but this is just about the slowest algorithm out there for computing the NPMLE. This could be a problem with n > 500, for example (also depends on the number of unique interval times). In `interval`, you can chose other faster algorithms with the `initfit` option; for example, I believe currently the fastest option would be to set `initfit = 'initcomputeMLE'`. The package also includes various plotting and testing functions.

Currently, the fastest algorithm available is `ic_np` in the `icenReg` package (note: this is the author). This can be fit as

`npmle_fit <- ic_np(cbind(l, r) ~ 0, data = myData)`

(where l and r are variables for the left and right side of the intervals in the dataset myData). And the plot can be produced by

`plot(npmle_fit)`

However, this is currently not compatible with the `interval` functions, which can do a lot more with the NPMLE than just plot it. So unless speed is *really* a huge issue, you may want to stick with `interval`.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the gte package for R.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @A.Rowland. At present this is really more of a comment than an answer. Would you mind expanding on this? What is the `gte` package? How would it help resolve the OP's issue? Perhaps you could even provide a quick demonstration.

Comment: This is indeed an appropriate answer to the question as asked.  But the only reason this question had been left open on our site (and not closed as off topic) is that there is some prospect it will be interpreted as a *statistical* question, whose answers will provide some information about the method it names, rather than as a mere reference to a package. Whence @gung's request for an expanded response, which would be very welcome.